# Joint distribution function if it is geometric and X is uniform

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ be uniform on the set $\{\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 14\}$, and the distribution of $Y\mid X = x$ is geometric with parameter $x$; that is, $P(Y=k\mid X=x) = x(1-x)^k$ for $k=0, 1, 2,\dotsc $

How do I find the pmf of this? I'm not sure how X being uniform on that set affects the distribution, which is what is confusing me.

And conversely, how would I then obtain $X\mid Y=k$ for $k=0, 1, 2,\dotsc$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$\Pr(Y=k)=\frac{1}{3}\Pr\left(Y=k|X=1/2\right)+\frac{1}{3}\Pr\left(Y=k|X=1/3\right)+\frac{1}{3}\Pr\left(Y=k|X=1/4\right).$$
You have given an explicit formula for the required conditional probabilities.

For the second problem, we have 
$$\Pr(X=t|Y=k)\Pr(Y=k)=\Pr(Y=k|X=t)\Pr(X=t)$$ for $t=1/2, 1/3,1/4$. We have expressions for three of these, so we can find the fourth.

Comment: They are known. In all cases they are $0,1,2,3,\dots$. To put things concretely, we have $3$ coins, one with probability $1/2$ of head, another with probability $1/3$, another with probability $1/4$. We choose a coin at random, keep tossing until we get a head. Then $Y$ is the number of tails we get. For the first probability calculation, I conditioned on the coin we happened to choose.

Comment: Yes, your calculation of $\Pr(Y=k)$ is correct.

Comment: In the second displayed formula, for no good reason I used $\Pr(X=t)$. For all values of $t$, this is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The coin story is because I find it easiest to solve a problem by viewing it concretely.

Comment: You would also have to sum over all $k$. Instead, I would use conditional expectation, since we know the expectations of the geometrics.